# How to Init a pointer of struct in a struct properly in Golang

Tags: go, struct

I have a generated struct that looks like this:

```
type a_weird_struct struct {
    a *string
    b *string
    c *struct {
        d *int
        e *int
        f *int
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to initialize this struct? Specifically, the struct pointer `c`.

Comment: There are two options that I can think of, one is to copy c and define in the go file where it used, the other one is to use reflection to dynamic generate a "declaration", but both looked not very pretty.

Answer (score 1):

try to init pointer like this

```
func initPointer() {
    astr, bstr := "xxxx", "yyyy"
    dint, eint, fint := 1, 2, 3
    x := &a_weird_struct{
        a: &astr,
        b: &bstr,
        c: &(struct {
            d *int
            e *int
            f *int
        }{
            d: &dint,
            e: &eint,
            f: &fint,
        }),
    }
     fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Comment: This works, but is there any way that can avoid copy a struct definition?

Comment: As far as I know there is no other way. Because you use the anonymous structure definition.

Answer (score -1):

```
func PointOf[T any](value T) *T {
    return &value
}

a_weird_struct{
    a: PointOf("a"),
    b: PointOf("b"),
    c: &struct{d *int; e *int; f *int}{
        PointOf(1),
        PointOf(2),
        PointOf(3),
    },
}
```

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: the question is asking how to initialize `c`, not how to initialize struct pointer members with literals